# Inconsistent Functions behavior

Tags: elixir

I'm trying out a `square` and a `cube` function. 
Why does `square` work while `cube` blows up?

```
square = &1 * &1
square.(5)
```

Works fine while

```
cube = &1 * &1 * &1
cube.(5)
```

Throws

```
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    :erlang.*(#Function<erl_eval.6.82930912>, 5)
    erl_eval.erl:572: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    src/elixir.erl:133: :elixir.eval_forms/3
    /private/tmp/elixir-OVih/elixir-0.8.2/lib/iex/lib/iex/server.ex:19: IEx.Server.do_loop/1
```

Comment: Edited out the `Erlang` tag from this post. It is more for the Elixir folks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Quoting Alexei Sholik on the elixir-talk mailing list:

> Normally, &1 only makes into a function the primitive expression it belongs to. In other words, it walks up the AST to the first parent and replaces that parent with a fn.

Expressions like this work just fine:

```
&1 * &1
&1 + 2
&1 * &2
```

But it can't be involved in a more complicated expression.

For instance, when you write:

```
&1 * &1 * &1
```

... you're writing something akin to:

```
fn x -> fn x -> x * x end * x end
```

There's discussion on elixir-core about whether the behavior of `&1` needs to be modified to be less confusing in these cases.

To answer your specific question, though, you want something more like this:

```
cube = fn x -> x * x * x end
```

If you want to use `&1`, you can use a simple expression with `math.pow/2`:

```
cube = :math.pow(&1, 3)
```

... note that `math.pow/2` always gives back a float.

Comment: the more I use elixir, the more I feel that the devs don't know how to write a parser.

Answer (score 55):

Since [0.10.3](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0103-2013-10-02) you need to put the partial application between parentheses preceded by the `&` operator.

You won't have any trouble with this version:

```
iex> square = &(&1 * &1)
iex> square.(5)
25
iex> cube = &(&1 * &1 * &1)
iex> cube.(5)
125
```

Comment: +1 - OP @Benjamin Tan - read http://pragprog.com/book/elixir/programming-elixir for the latest

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest Elixir [documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html) there are two ways to create anonymous functions:

```
# first one, more explicit
cube = fn x -> x * x * x end

#second one, syntactic sugar applied
cube = &(&1*&1*&1)

#calling them is the same
IO.puts cube.(8) # should be 512
```